# How to generate a unit tests in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-testing

I read the official doc for generating the unit tests but it is too messy. I have to generate a unit test cases for the `AdminPasswordChangeForm`, and two defined function in `views.py` which are changing the status of `is_staff` and `is_active`.

I have also wrote simple test cases to register an user. Follow is the method defined in `views.py` (which are updating the password using `AdminPasswordChangeForm`)

```
def user_change_password(request, id):
     user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
     form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(user, request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         new_user = form.save()
         msg = _('Password changed successfully.')
         request.user.message_set.create(message=msg)
         return HttpResponseRedirect('../../user/users')
     else:
         form = AdminPasswordChangeForm(user)
     extra_context = {            
         'form': form,
         'change': True
         }
     return direct_to_template(request,"users/user_password_change.html",
                 extra_context = extra_context)
```

Comment: I want to write unit test case for a method defined in views.py i.e user_change password(above written in question).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tutorials on how to write tests.  Django Documentation (like always) does a great job of explaining what their framework offers in terms of testing.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs
In addition there are many articles/slideshows covering WHAT to test.
http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/

As far as HOW to test a view you have a couple of options

You can use the built in request factory to generate a request object and call your function directly.  You can make sure a redirect is returned if appropriate or a template or whatever you are expecting.

Or you can make a request to the url in your urls.py file.

I mean to test `AdminPasswordChangeForm` instantiate it with a user object and a POST dictionary.  Check to make sure it is creating the correct form, If you haven't customized it too much you can skip testing it becuase django does a great job of testing their code.